# (mingW) Why does g++ not recognise my class definition when compiling a python extension?

Tags: c++, python, mingw, swig

So I am working on a small python extension using the SWIG library. I use 3 commands to compile the extension. the first 2 ones use gcc, and the final one g++, giving a python extension as a result. My problem is that after gcc compiles the code with no errors, g++ starts to complain it can not find one of my class definitions (more details below). I can't debug it very much, because the part it actually complains about is a binary file. How am I supposed to define the class to the g++ compiler?

The code that is giving problems consists of a function inside a file called "cpprenderer.cpp", which creates an instance of the class mesh, defined in "mesh.cpp". Of course I have a header file defining that class, and link to it from cpprenderer.cpp.

My code:
excerpt from cpprenderer.cpp:

```
#include "src/mesh.h"
int addMesh()
{
    int newMesh = displayList.size();
    mesh meshObj = mesh();
    displayList.push_back(meshObj);
    return newMesh;
}
```

And this is the complete mesh.h header file:

```
class mesh
{
public:
    mesh(void);
    void render(void);
    int createGroup(void);

    float rotationX;
    float rotationY;
    float rotationZ;

    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};
```

Finally, these are the commands I use, and what their output is:

```
C:\Users\Bart\Desktop\swig test>cd C:\Users\Bart\Desktop\swig test
C:\Users\Bart\Desktop\swig test>C:\swig\swig.exe -python -c++ cpprenderer.i
C:\Users\Bart\Desktop\swig test>c:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\python26\include -IC:\python26\PC -c cpprenderer_wrap.cxx -o build\temp.win32-2. \Release\cpprenderer_wrap.o "-lopengl32 -lglu32 -lgdi32 -lglut32"
C:\Users\Bart\Desktop\swig test>c:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\python26\include -IC:\python26\PC -c cpprenderer.cpp -o build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\cpprenderer.o "-lopengl32 -lglu32 -lgdi32 -lglut32"
C:\Users\Bart\Desktop\swig test>c:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe -mno-cygwin -shared -s build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\cpprenderer_wrap.o build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\cpprenderer.o -LC:\python26\libs -LC:\python26\PCbuild -lpython26 -lmsvcr90 -lopengl32 -lglu32 -lgdi32 -lglut32 -o "C:\Users\Bart\Desktop\swig test\_cpprenderer.pyd" 
build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\cpprenderer.o:cpprenderer.cpp:(.text+0x697): undefined reference to `mesh::mesh()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As you can see gcc compiles my code fine, but when g++ does its thing, it fails to find the definition of my mesh constructor, which I define in my header file.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the compiler is finding the *declaration* just fine, but not the *definition*.  In other words, you've prototyped the constructor, but you haven't implemented it anywhere.  From the compiler output it doesn't seem like you're linking in your .cpp file containing the implementation, which is likely the cause of this problem.

Comment: Hm. I have a file called "mesh.cpp" which has an implementation of the class. Do I need to include that one separately? (yeah, I am very new to C++)

Comment: You'll need to compile that along with everything else.  Header files are sort of like a menu - they tell you what's available - but they (often) don't have any actual implementation code in them.  Compiling the .cpp file along with the rest of the files pairs the implementation with the interface specified in the header file.

Comment: Well, right now you're issuing a series of commands to compile a few other files.  Just add a command to compile your .cpp file, and then in the final build step where you link together the .o files, add the new .o file.  I'm not sure what toolchain you're using, so I can't offer any more specific advice than that.

Comment: ok. I'll take a look. What are those .o files exactly? are they some kind of intermediate form between the compilation steps?

Comment: @Bartvlb- A .o file is called an "object file."  C++ compilation proceeds in several phases, of which two are important for now.  During *compilation*, the compiler generates an *object file* containing a compiled representation of the C++ file, but without any links between functions resolved.  This is the .o file.  During *linking*, the *linker* takes all the .o files and confirms that all expected functions are defined, then outputs machine code based on the object code, but with function references resolved.

Comment: I needed to compile the mesh file separately. After some arguing about some other stuff it finally compiled fine. thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @Bartvbl- Glad to hear that it worked!  Don't forget to accept the answer if it's useful. ;-)